# Regular expression

Tags: regex

```
((\b2\d{9}\b.*)(\n)?){5,}
```

I have create regular expression that it will be detect this no 2473008742 5 times or greater than 5 times. for e.g

```
2473008742
2473008742
2473008742
2473008742
2473008742
```

But it is detecting it detects whole line. I just want to detect only this no when it exist 5 times or grater than 5 no.. is there any solution

Comment: The `.*` part matches the rest of the line. Perhaps omit that part, and use anchors `^(?:2\d{9}\n?){5,}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird: You're missing the space, this should work: `^(?:2\d{9}[ \n]?){5,}`

Comment: @PoulBak I have updated the formatting in the question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern starts with a word boundary `\b2` which can also start a match at another position than the start of the string.

Then after matching the 9 digits and the word boundary `\d{9}\b` the `.*` matches the rest of the line.

To not allow other leading characters, you can start the pattern with an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string, and to not match the rest of the line remove the `.*` part

For example

```
^(2\d{9}\n?){5,}
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/33VjWa/1).

- Note that you don't need the capture group here `(\n)?`.
- If you don't need a capture group, you can make the outer group a non capture group `(?:` because repeating a capture group will capture the value of the last iteration.